# Regular expression to find specific string and replace characters using a certain mask in notepad++

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

Yet I am too weak in RegEx, so I need your help. I've got for example:

```
" on 23%"
```

How can I use RegEx to get it converted into:

```
" to 23%"
```

but to leave digits untouched? Note that "23" could be any 2 digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive lookaround assertions like below.

**Find what:**

```
(?<= )on(?= \d+%)
```

**Replace With:**

```
to
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mI7qF6/4)

Comment: Sry, how can I use it in 'search and replace'? It doesn't work in it =/

Comment: use regex find and replace function.

Comment: enable the tick mark which was just under to the down arrow. like http://i.stack.imgur.com/XANpB.png